# WebView doesn't get drawn, WARN/webcore(5336): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Tags: android, layout, view, webview, draw

My app has a view that gets added to activity programmatically using this code:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(480, 75);

    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)mMyView.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(mMyView);
    }

    activity.addContentView(mMyView, layoutParams);`
```

After pressing the Back Button, which ofcourse calls OnDestroy(), and running the app again, I don't see the View get drawn on the screen, and I get this warning on DDMS when it tries to draw it:

**WARN/webcore(5336): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout**

It's worth mentioning that the view is functional on this state (the page resources are being loaded, according to the log on DDMS)

Other "regular" views (ImageView, TextView) that are also in the same ContentView are drawing fine.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem, or what can be its source?

Comment: in what method do you run this code? anymore stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using parent.forceLayout() then call parent.measure().

This forces the layout to redraw itself without any regard for other layout requests (and doesn't redraw the parent views), and then remeasures it with current specs.

Hope this helps!