# Webview is showing in android 5, but not in 2.3?

Tags: android, view, webview

The only warning in my logcat is:

> `webcore: Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout.`

I have an ad banner using a webview in my app which is added programmatically. It shows up in Android version 5, but not in Android 2.3. I've tested XML instead of java, searched a lot of other posts involving the same error, but none solved my problem!
The log is not from stack trace in the code. It comes from the Banner class which is locked and i don't have access to it. I'm really frustrated. I have seen many posts regarding this issue, none suited my case. Help please!

```
public class Users extends Activity{

static boolean showAd = true;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users);
    try{
        if (showAd)
            showBanner();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 private void showBanner(){
   try {
       Banner banner = new Banner(this);
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.users);
       layout.addView(banner);
   } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253337/webview-doesnt-get-drawn-warn-webcore5336-cant-get-the-viewwidth-after-the?rq=1

Comment: I have already used that. Didn't work for me. Same warning, no result:(

Comment: Please show your full code so that we can debug it. @saraX

Comment: The code i use is just the above. I call showBanner from onCreate() and it starts working. That's all i do! But the library is a modified google ads library and is locked. When i try to open any class in the library, it shows a "Source not found" message! So there is no hope? @CrazyAndroid

Comment: I mean the whole class file @saraX

Comment: Where is the showAd method or variable you have defined?@saraX

Comment: Added the boolean showAd then!

Comment: Have you noticed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743051/w-webcore2733-cant-get-the-viewwidth-after-the-first-layout ?

Comment: Yes, and the funny is that the link is no longer available!@Vaiden

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I got the link for the source code

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AdBanner in android like this:

Define an adview in a XML:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.flash.light"
    android:id="@+id/add_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXX"/>
```

Then in your Activity you should proceed like this:

```
public class BannerSample extends Activity {
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.add_view);      
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();               
adview.loadAd(re);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your banner like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.users);
layout.addView (banner, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.requestlayout();
```

I checked the source code for the Android [WebViewCore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0cccec0a9bdc59700a4720daf5ac5f4c86b6ed14/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java) and found your error at line **1960** in the updateViewport method.

The message is logged when:

```
if (viewportWidth == 0) {
                Log.w(LOGTAG, "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout");
            }
```

the viewportWidth is calculated like that:

```
webViewWidth = mWebView.getViewWidth();
```

so in your case  it seems that the webview width is set to Zero, I suggest double checking your Layout xml file to make sure that the webview and it's parent ViewGroup dimensions are properly set.

Comment: I did it but same warning, can't get the viewWidth after first layout :(

Comment: Still the same. Should i cry?:( . These codes work on Galaxy note 3 with Lollipop but not on xperia ray with Gingerbread. Doesn't this give any clue?

Comment: I  checked again and found nothing wrong! So i managed to find a new ICS rom for Xperia Ray and flashed the rom, so the device updated to ICS. Again i tested the app and this time, Ad banner worked like a charm! Now I'm sure it's a matter of android version 2.3. :(